# One liner variable declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Declaring global variables is easy, you just put the identifier followed by equals and the value you want. You can do this anywhere, like when setting arguments for a function call or inside a loop. But when I want this
variable to be local things seem to get more restricted. I can't declare a local variable in a function call, and putting `var x=i+3;` inside a loop would just re-declare the variable over and over. Is there something I overlooked in the documentations? Or is this just the way it is?

```
...
obj.do_my_thing(cached_int = 4 + cars.amount(), true);
...

for( var e in list ) cached_float += cached_int/0.5;
console.log(cached_float);
...
```

What I would like todo is:

```
...
obj.do_my_thing(var cached_int = 4 + cars.amount(), true);
...

for( var e in list ) var cached_float += cached_int/0.5;
console.log(cached_float);
...
```

Comment: I think you need to add some ***clear*** code examples to this question to illustrate what you mean, because at the moment, it isn't all that clear.

Comment: Why would you like to prepend the assignments with `var` keyword? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to answer my own question for all the people like me who skimmed the internet for a solution for the same "problem": You can simply declare locally-scoped variables in the parameters of your function declaration. This way you don't need to set up variables with the var keyword:

```
function q(param){
  var b = my_array.indexOf(param);
  if(b!=-1) my_array.splice(b,1);
}

function p(param, b){
  if((b=my_array.indexOf(param))!=-1) my_array.splice(b,1); // ♥ ♥ ♥
}

p('hello world');
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't declare a local variable in a function call

If you are trying to access same variable from two calls to same function, you will have to declare the variable in an outer scope

E.g.

```
function foo() {
    var i = 0;
    function bar() {
        i++;
    }
    bar();
    alert(i);//1
    bar();
    alert(i);//2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can't declare a local variable in a function call

Yes you can:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 1;    // Local variable
    window.baz = 2; // Global variable
}

foo();

console.log(bar); // Undefined
console.log(baz); // 2
```

---

> ...and putting var x=i+3; inside a loop would just re-declare the variable over and over

You can declare your variable outside of the loop:

```
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    x = i + 3;

console.log(x); // 1002
```

---

> This is fine, but not as elegant as it would be if I could just declare the local variable 'on-the-go'.

You can to an extent:

```
for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Declare window.x if it doesn't already exist
    if (!window.x)
        window.x = 0;

    x = i + 3;
}

console.log(x); // 1002
```

---

> I'm sorry, but I believe that window.x is global. If that is what you mean.

You can assign the variable to your function:

```
function foo() {
    for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++) {
        // Declare foo.x if it doesn't already exist
        if (!foo.x)
            foo.x = 0;

        x = i + 3;
    }

    console.log(x); // 1002
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but not as elegant as it would be if I could just declare the local variable 'on-the-go'.

Comment: @JohnSmith could you elaborate on 'on-the-go'?

Comment: Look at the above example I posted.

Comment: @JohnSmith I've proved an *on-the-go* example in my edited answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe that window.x is global. If that is what you mean.

Comment: window.x is global indeed. But its unclear what you want. Do you want a different variable for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: No, I want a local variable that I can declare the way I would declare a global variable. It's really not all that complicated.

Comment: @JohnSmith I've updated my answer again to show how you can just assign the variable to the function...

Comment: I think that is still a global variable, James Donnelly. It's just a more specific namespace now.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I think you mean `foo.x = i + 3;` and `console.log(foo.x)`